# What are some intuitive ways to quantify a Kalman gain matrix in a single scalar?

Tags: kalman-filter

**Main question**

For debugging purposes I want to know what the Kalman gain is at each step of a Kalman Filter, and specifically, if it's "large" or "small" so I get an understanding of what the interpolation between prior and measurement (see diagram below from https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python) might look like.

[image]

What are some quantities I could compute for the matrix that might give me such a hint?

**More advanced**

I'm aware that some components of my state space and measurement space may have very different relative covariances and so it won't always make sense to summarize the Kalman gain in one number, but let's assume I have a good grasp on which parts of the measurement space relate to which parts of the state space and the parts are fairly independent. This might mean I'd want to break the Kalman matrix up into a few slices and summarise each slice with a single scalar. I'd also like to know how to do that.

Comment: My take on the main question is that I'd want to know about how the Kalman gain matrix squeezes or stretches space when moving from measurement space to state space. So use something like a determinant? But non-square matrices do not have determinants.

Comment: I am unsure what exactly you are asking. Would for example taking the [Frobenius norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) of the Kalman gain match this?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen are you unsure of the question or my comment? Perhaps the frobenius norm could be interesting but I think it could sometimes be misleading if negative terms in the matrix cancel with positive terms in the matrix when carrying the multiplication through. Others have suggested using the product of singular values which might be more robust to that effect.

Comment: When I made my comment I didn't read your comment yet (maybe also add it to the question itself?). But from your comment I would indeed agree that the singular value decomposition would suite this the best. Then you could manipulate those singular values in different ways, depending on your needs (does it have to be only one value?), maybe the ratio between smallest and biggest could also be useful.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen no it doesn't have to be only one value (as per the "advanced" part of my question). But yes in the end I settled on product of singular values with the condition number as another indicator.